# Same page Navigation within a JqueryMobile page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have a page using Jquery Mobile. I have attempted to use simple anchors

```
<a href="#section1">Text</a>


<div id="section1"> 
text
</div>
```

but it seems like that isn't possible when calling Jquery Mobile. Does anyone know of a usable work around? I've searched for a while and can't seem to find anything that actually works. I'm trying to simply move down to certain sections in the same html document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$.mobile.navigate( "#section1" );`

```
<a href="#section1" onclick="$.mobile.navigate( '#section1' );">Text</a>

<div id="section1"> 
text
</div>
```

Document: https://api.jquerymobile.com/jQuery.mobile.navigate/

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much.